# Gcloud Dataflow Step Execution Time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using gcloud dataflow job and want individual execution times for all the steps in my dataflow including nested transforms. I'm using a streaming dataflow and the pipeline currently looks like this:

[Current dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGfuv.png)

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I do not see what this has to do with programming. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!

Answer (score 3):

Answer is WallTime. You can access this info by clicking one of the task in your pipeline(even nested). 
Elapsed time of a job is the total time takes to complete your dataflow job while wall time is the sum time taken to run each step by the assigned workers. See the below image for more details.

[image: For example]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but upon clicking the step I only see the system lag for the step. How do I get to see the wall the time? or is it something that we have configure while making the dataflow?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of what you're referring to? There's no need to configure as code in dataflow programming. The time written on individual steps is the wall time.

Comment: This is what my dataflow pipeline looks like and I don't have "wall time" anywhere in the steps. do we need to configure it somewhere so that it shows up when we click on individual steps? (screenshot of my dataflow https://imgur.com/BBVidoG)

Comment: elapsed time is the total time since the job started. If it is a batching job, it is the same to total time takes to complete your dataflow job. However streaming job is different.